# Same app but different builds on separated Play Store accounts

Tags: android, ios, google-play, package-name, uat

We currently have a Play Store account with an application in production state. This application has a package name (com.foo.live) and it is uses the live environment.

Sometimes our customers asks for test versions of the application which uses different test environments - and having a different package name (com.foo.test).

Our main goal is to handover these test versions via Play Store alpha/beta state to UAT, but we can't upload the test builds to our currently existing app profile because the package name must be unique.

We are planning to create separated application profiles for these test environment applications but we are not sure is there any best practice for it in our current situation? This version will never be opened/live to Store users.

We are afraid of violation if we are using almost the same name. We are thinking about "App name Test" or "App name Integ" names but as far as I know Google will complain if we have test/integrational/etc. in our app name, and may violate for that there is already a similiary named app.

Do you have any experience/tips how to evade naming violations in our situation? (Maybe for iOS App Store where we are planning the same practice)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app stores, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add those customers who requires test environment in beta channel as a registered user?

You can create an app by changing only endpointt url to staging / testing environment and upload in beta channel and your customers can access this build , once your customer approves on this build remove apk from beta channel and upload production apk to play store.